# How to fix Java error "Unresolved compilation problem" in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, combobox

I'm trying to dabble with a basic ComboBox (i hear these are very outdated). The goal is to create a box with options for the user and when they click said option in the ComboBox they will get information from an array of strings based on the case detected by the switch. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SolicitorComBox extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String[] MuniArray = {"Allepo", "Avalon"};
    JComboBox MuniList = new JComboBox (MuniArray);
JLabel lblText = new JLabel();

public static void main (String[] args) { 
    SolicitorComBox fr = new SolicitorComBox();
    centerFrame(fr);
    fr.setVisible(true);


}
private static void centerFrame(SolicitorComBox fr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public SolicitorComBox() {
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    setSize (400, 300);
    setTitle ("Solicitor Search");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MuniList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    MuniList.addActionListener(this);
    add(MuniList);
    add(lblText);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getsource() == MuniList) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox).e.getsource();
        String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        switch (msg) {
            case "Allepo": lblText.setText("The attorney is Joe!");
            break;
            case "Avalon": lblText.setText("The attorney is Dana!");
            break;
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try to run the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at SolicitorComBox.main(SolicitorCombobox.java:10)
```

Comment: It looks you didn't post the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beside the fact you didn't post your whole code, I was able to run the piece of code you put over there:

[image]

So or your issue is below the code you posted, or it is just a compilation problem in your IDE

I would recommend to you manually refresh your project and force clean it using the menu `Project > Clean` in Eclipse. I will force your app to recompile.

Comment: Thank you! that is all the code i have written currently as i wanted to test the it before creating any further cases. Do you think i am missing plugins? I am going to try what you suggested right now. Thank you for this response!

Comment: I tried your suggestion and i am still getting the same error. Perhaps i am missing required plug-ins?

Comment: As far as I know it is not need to install any plugins to compile it, since it is just Java. Anyway try to install WindowBuilder in the Eclipse Marketplace and open your class in the design mode, maybe it could help you find the issue.

Comment: What version of eclipse did you run this in?

Comment: Eclipse Neon, with JDK 1.8

Comment: Hmm ok im using eclipse oxygen think that might be an issue?

Comment: Don't think so, but if it brings comfort to your heart try changing the versions :)

Comment: I did and it did nothing :(. I honestly cant figure out why you can run this and i cant. Thanks for all the help you've been giving, though. Idk what to do at this point. Might just re code it again in a new project.

Comment: Yep, try again from a clean slate.

Comment: Got it running! but i think i wrote something wrong the idea is when they click on the dropdown box and and make a selection, it is supposed to display the message in the case but it is not. Any ideas/

Comment: You will have to debug the actionPerformed method, check if it is even getting inside it.

Comment: Yes it says there is no method value in the debugger for the method in line 36. Not sure why that is though as it is assigned to the correct muniList.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was using an imported gradle project but running it from inside eclipse. For some reason the error suddenly started to appear.

Solution 1. In eclipse click **clean** then **refresh**. This worked, but not for very long

Solution 2. Gradle has an eclipse task for interacting with the eclipse environment and making sure its libs are correct: So running **gradle clean build eclipse** seemed to provide a solution. Presumably maven has a similar task.

Answer (score 0):

you may be missing some jar files. Right click on your project or class,  goto build path and select "build path configuration". from the "build path" window,  select "libraries" tab,  find the missing files,  download them and put the in your project from the "project explorer" side.  you can use drag and drop. 
Now click on "Add JARs" to add the jar files to the library from the project.

it worked for me.  hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix Java error “Unresolved compilation problem” in Eclipse IDE follow these steps :**

- Try to `include package name` in eclipse in case if you forgot it
- **Import all packages before using it**, EX: `import java.util.Scanner` before using Scanner class.
- Also make sure to check **compiler compliance level** and **selected jdk version** is same

I eclipse, if you skip including package it will give **"Unresolved compilation problem"**